# Shave off all but X digits off a value?

Tags: math

I'm sure this has already been answered before, but I wasn't sure what to search to find it.

Anyways I am having trouble with what should be a super basic math problem. Basically take a number and replace all the digits with 0s other than the first digit, or maybe the first two digits.

For example if the function gets 17 it should return 10. I've tried all sorts of ways to solve this but nothing it working. I've tried to convert the number into a string, convert the string into an array, convert the array into a number and multiply the result by 10 but that didn't work. I tried some math way of doing it. I believe it was something like:

x: value

n: digit to find

10 * (10 * (x / (10 ^ n)))

that gave back proper "shaved off" numbers but they seemed to be random and had no correlation to the original number. (like 17 would output 60 and 18 would output 20)

I also tried some way that used mod from a similar question on this site but that gave crazy large numbers that made no sense. I am absolutely terrible at math(why do i program right?) and this is just confusing me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically speaking simply you need to first calculate the total number of digits in the number given by continually dividing the number by 10 till it becomes 0. Let it be n.
Then the number x, the number of digits you want, you need to take the 10 raised to the power n-x, then divide the number given by this number 10 raised to the power n-x, in this way you would be able to get the required number of digits and then you simply need to multiply the number extracted by 10 raised to the Power n-x... Do the two steps independently of one another else you would not get the answer.
Hoping I would be helpful...
In case of any queries please feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you for the reply, however i found a different solution that works. your way works though